# Lost Transaction from Blockchain.com to Electrum

Tags: blockchain, electrum

This link, https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/a081d03519bc0f1dcf4ac391da6f54d4d6091c458530b620f96eca5c1c5a3511, shows the transaction was delivered to the address "1Mv4fi8UdVhbfm9iLx2Bf8xhDrMv9sZSyD" of my Electrum wallet, but my Electrum wallet doesn't show the transfer. Please teach me what is wrong. how I can find the truth? Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: In the Electrum window, on bottom right do you see a red circle or green circle?

Comment: Green. I have an Electrum wallet 3.3.8, latest version.